# PHP Macro Substitution

Tags: php

Consider this.

```
Var1= "Var2"
Var2= 100
```

I need to create a program that could act somewhat like this:

```
 Echo $Var1      (result: Var2)
 Echo ($Var1)    (result: 100)
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: That doesn't makes any sense!

Comment: Can you please develop your post so that we may at least understand what you want to do ?

Comment: It make any sense if you think STRICTLY in PHP.
What I want to do is find a way for the PHP "compiler" understand that when I use parenthesis (or anything else for that matter) I want to evaluate the content in $Var1, and it refer to another variable instead of just a string.
In other words, evaluate the content of $Var1 referring to $Var2, which content is 100.

Comment: Variable variables: `$$Var1` or `${$Var1}`.

Comment: I don't know why some people had voted my question negatively (which make my account to be blocked), while some others (thank you) had answered and had given even more details.
Anyhow, I am not going to bother you guys anymore, but before I leave I would like to give thanks the ones who answered.

Comment: One thing I do not get it: if some people do not understand the question why not simply ignore it?
Why vote negatively and make other people look bad?
What can possibly one get from that?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$Var1 = "Var2";
$Var2 = 100;
echo $$Var1;
// result output: "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables:

```
echo $$Var1;
```

You can do some weird stuff in PHP:

```
$one = 'anythingHere321';
$two = 'anything';
$three = 'here';

$anythingHere321 = 'It Works!';

echo $$one, '<br>';
echo ${$one}, '<br>';
echo ${$two . ucfirst($three) . (300 + 21)}, '<br>';
```

Basically, you can put pretty much anything inside `${}`, as long as it can be converted to a string. All these are valid:

```
${"string"};
${123};
${12.3};
${null};
${true};
${false};
```

Now, just because you *can* does not mean you *should*. You should use an array, or something like that, instead. Variable variables are more of a curiosity, or oddity, and not something you should use.

Comment: Thank you, Sverri. It definitely open up some possibilities.